# Database connectivity in windows form application

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms

I have created a Billing Software using windows forms and sql server 2012.
Now i'm very confused over many things regarding database connectivity. 
After making exe file, for installing in client machine i have to install sql server in client machine and configure the database then install my application. 
My doubt is.. is this how this procedure works? I downloaded some billing software from internet and how they work without configuring a database? and which is the best practice? should i install sql server in client machine ?

Comment: No. Install the SQL DB on a server and all clients connect to that server

Comment: then there should be a need of a network connection right. what if that shop has no net connection and how can we install as a stand alone one.

Comment: You might consider using a local database, such as SQLite

Comment: One option would be using *Microsoft SQL Server Compact*

Comment: @juergend sqlserver compact has been depreciated. instead you need to use sqlserver express or localdb

Comment: i have used sql server in my application. for sql server compact should i change whole code? Even if thats sql server compact how that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single standalone database per instance of the application - specific to the computer installed on - then you have a few options.

SQLite - https://sqlite.org/

SQL Server Express LocalDB (this is the 2016 version) -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Both of these run stand alone databases that can be embedded into your program using visual studio. There are others, but these are the ones I'm familiar with.

Syntax for SQLite has some differences to its syntax (mostly package specific) however SQL Server Express LocalDB runs the same T-SQL as the standard SQL Server package

Comment: i have created my app with sql server 2012, for sql server express localDB should i alter all my database related codes?

Comment: They should be ok - both packages use T-SQL. Think of localdb as a compact version you can embed within a program that doesnt require a server.

Comment: all i have is the backup of my database. can i use that in sql server express local db?

Comment: Indeed. Check out [this](http://www.alteridem.net/2016/03/24/restore-a-sql-server-backup-to-localdb/) link for guidance

Comment: but can that withstand high data from a supermarket?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to install SQL Server on the client machine. The clients connect via network to the central database using some database client drivers.

Assuming that you are using ADO.NET then you have configure the clients somehow to use the right connection string, where server name, database name etc. is contained.

Comment: what about if its a standalone client, or no network is involved?

Comment: What if that shop dont have network connections. and how the softwares we download from internet works without standalone sql server on machine or any networks?

Comment: @Takarii - that's leads to an important achitectural question which can only be answered, if more about the use cases is known. First of all, is there the need for the clients to synchronize their data ? The simplest case is that the clients are independent from each other. Then you can embed the database into your software by different means (OEM Version from Microsoft SQL) or SQLLite.